# Бесконечно создаётся тело box2d

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

Динамическое тело ball должно создаваться один раз, но вместо этого происходит вот это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public class Main extends ApplicationAdapter {

OrthographicCamera cam;
final float TIME_STEP = 60f;
final int VELOCITY_ITERATIONS = 6;
final int POSITION_ITERATIONS = 2;
public static final int WIDTH  = 480;
public static final int HEIGHT = 720;
World world;
Box2DDebugRenderer debugRenderer;
Body bat;
ArrayList<Body> ballList = new ArrayList<Body>();

@Override
public void create () {
    world = new World(new Vector2(0,-10),true);
    debugRenderer = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
    world.setContactListener(new BrickContactListener());
    cam = new OrthographicCamera(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
    initObjects();
}

@Override
public void render () {
    debugRenderer.render(world,cam.combined);
    world.step(TIME_STEP,VELOCITY_ITERATIONS,POSITION_ITERATIONS);
}

@Override
public void dispose () {

    world.dispose();

}
private void initObjects(){
    bat = createBat();
    createBall(0,0);
    //createBricks();
}
private Body createBat(){
    Body bat;
    BodyDef batBodyDef = new BodyDef();
    batBodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.KinematicBody;
    batBodyDef.fixedRotation = true;
    batBodyDef.position.set(0,-HEIGHT/2+HEIGHT/8);
    bat = world.createBody(batBodyDef);
    PolygonShape polygonShape = new PolygonShape();
    polygonShape.setAsBox(50,10);
    bat.createFixture(polygonShape,10f);
    polygonShape.dispose();
    return bat;
}
private void createBall(float x,float y){
    Body ball;
    BodyDef ballBodyDef = new BodyDef();
    ballBodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    ballBodyDef.position.set(x,y);
    ball = world.createBody(ballBodyDef);
    CircleShape circleShape = new CircleShape();
    circleShape.setRadius(10f);
    ball.createFixture(circleShape,1f);
    circleShape.dispose();
    ballList.add(ball);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С созданием объектов у тебя все верно. Нужно проcто очистить экран:

```
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    debugRenderer.render(world,cam.combined);
    world.step(TIME_STEP,VELOCITY_ITERATIONS,POSITION_ITERATIONS);
}
```